# How did jQuery select the elements by CSS selector before matches, querySelector and querySelectorAll have been supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wondered how did jQuery select the elements by CSS selector when `matches`, `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` wasn't supported. It is difficult to parse the CSS selector (the more complicated the CSS selector is, the more difficult it is to parse), let alone convert into DOM elements. Therefore, how did jQuery select the elements by CSS selector in the old version browsers?

Comment: It uses a library called `Sizzle`.

Comment: It also still uses this when you use selectors with jQuery extensions.

Comment: jQuery is open source, you can see how it works. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=

Comment: Thank you, Barmar